# Alternative concepts for tangent spaces of smooth manifolds and derivatives of smooth maps

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, reference-request, tangent-spaces

The derivative of a smooth  map $f : U \to V$ between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^m, V \subset \mathbb R^n$ at $p \in U$ is a linear map $df_p : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ which is charcterized by the well-known property $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\lVert (f(p +h) - (f(p) + df_p(h))\rVert}{\lVert h \rVert} = 0$. This concept relies on the linear structures of domain and range of $f$ which are given locally around $p$ and $f(p)$.

For a smooth  map $f : M \to N$ from an $m$-manifold $M$ to an $n$-manifold $N$ this not work because we do not have (in general) canonical linear structures around $p$ and $f(p)$. We can of course choose charts $\phi : U \to U'$ on $M$ around $p$ and $\psi : V \to V'$ on $N$ around $f(p)$ and get a "localized derivative"
$$d_{(\phi,\psi)} f_p  = d(\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} .$$
But this depends on the choice of local Euclidean coordinates around $p$ and $f(p)$ so that $d_{(\phi,\psi)} f_p$ does not seem to be a good concept of a derivative of $f$ at $p$. Indeed the derivative of $f$ at $p$ is usually understood as a linear map $df_p : T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$ between tangent spaces.

The tangent space $T_pM$ is defined either as the set of derivations $C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$ at $p$ or as the set of "derivatives $u'(0)$ of curves $u : J \to M$ through $p$". Such $u$ is a smooth map defined on an open interval $J \subset \mathbb  R$ with $0 \in J$ and $u(0) = p$ and the derivative (whatever its definition may be) is taken at $t =0$. The approach via derivations is very abstract; in my opinion the approach via curves is more intuitive and better for motivational purposes. However, it involves a "preliminary" concept of derivative using the following fact: Although we do not yet have an interpretation of $u'(0)$ we can at least say what it means that two curves $u,v$ have the *same derivative* at $0$: This can be characterized by the requirement that $(\phi \circ u)'(0) = (\phi \circ v)'(0)$ for all charts $\phi : U \to U'$ around $p$. Note that this equation holds for *some* chart, then it holds for *all* charts. Having the same derivative at $0$ is an equivalence relation for curves through $p$ and one defines $u'(0) = [u]$ = equivalence class of $u$. In my eyes this is a strange interpretation of "derivative", but formally it does make sense.

A similar phenomenon occurs in the context of the cotangent space $T^*_pM$. One approach is to define it as the set of equivalence classes of maps $f \in C^\infty(M)$ with respect to the equivalence relation of having the same derivative at $p$ which is defined via chart $\phi : U \to U'$ around $p$ by considering $d(f \circ \psi^{-1})_{\psi^{-1}(p)}$. Some authors write $df_p = [f]$ (e.g. [Hitchin p. 17](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/%7Ejoyce/Nairobi2019/Hitchin-DifferentiableManifolds.pdf); see also [Hitchin's definition of tangent space and tangent vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230215)).

**My questions:**

1. The same thing could be done for smooth maps $f : M \to N$ by considering equivalence classes of smooth maps $M \to N$ with respect to the equivalence relation of having the same derivative at $p$, the latter being defined via charts. That is, $df_p = [f]$. Does this occur anywhere in the literature and does it have any use?
2. Is there an alternative approach to define $T_pM$ (and also $T^*_pM$) not in terms of equivalence classes of curves, but in a more persuavive form? A vague idea would be that the set of derivatives of curves through a point $p$ of an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$ is nothing else than $\mathbb R^m$ itself. So why not take $T_pM = (\mathbb R^m,\phi)$, where $\phi : U \to U'$ is a fixed chart around $p$? This would involve the axiom of choice to assign charts $\phi$ to points $p$, but isn't it okay?

Comment: What is the reason you are asking? In any case, you can simply work with submanifolds of $R^N$ and then use "geometric" tangent vectors. This is how it's done in the book by Guillemin and Pollack. If one teaches an undergraduate class, this approach is somewhat better since it requires less sophistication on the part of the students.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am aware that for submanifolds we have a really good "geometric" variant of the tangent space.  Perhaps this is the best access for beginners.  I was interested in the method of generalizing "geometric" tangent vectors of submanifolds to "abstract" tangent vectors of arbitrary manifolds $M$.  A standard approach is to consider derivatives of curves in $M$, but then a tangent vector is defined as an equivalence of such curves. This seems a bit strange, the original derivatives are "hidden" in equivalence classes of maps (which contain many maps different from the given $f$) .

Comment: I understand that it works, but I asked myself whether there are alternatives closer to the original derivative idea. For submanifolds no equivalence classes of curves are needed, it suffices to consider  ordinary derivatives of  curves in $\mathbb R^N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1.

I have not seen it in the literature, but my knowledge is limited.

Question 2.

The idea to take $T_pM = (\mathbb R^m,\phi)$, where $\phi : U \to U'$ is a fixed chart around $p$, is nice. It means that you identify the tangent space $T_pM$ with $\mathbb R^m$ via a chart $\phi$ around $p$. This is completely legitimate, but I do not think that one should choose a specific $\phi$. Instead one should take into account all charts $\phi$ and "glue" the associated copies of $\mathbb R^m$ via the differentials of the transition functions. Let us make this precise. This will involve a lot of formalism and  it is not as intuitive as you expect. The approach is purely requirements-based; its focus is to explicitly formulate our expectations regarding tangent spaces.

On an abstract level, we want to associate to each point $p$ of an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$ an $m$-dimensional *tangent vector space* $T_pM$ specified by the following requirements:

1. If $M$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$, then $T_p M = \mathbb R^m$ (or more precisely, there exists a *canonical isomorphism* $T_pM \to \mathbb R^m$). This is a reasonable requirement: In any conceivable interpretation the set of all tangent vectors at $p$ should be nothing else than $\mathbb R^m$. **It is the intuitive part of our approach.**
2. The tangent space $T_pM$ is *determined locally*, i.e. $T_p M = T_pU$ for each open neigborhood $U$ of $p$. Again we can require more generally that there exists a *canonical isomorphism* $T_pU \to T_pM$.
3. Each chart $\phi : U \to U'$ around $p$ induces a specific isomorphism $d\phi_p : T_pM = T_pU \to T_{\phi(p)}U' = \mathbb R^m$.
4. Given two charts $\phi, \psi$ around $p$, we have $d\psi_p \circ d\phi_p^{-1} = d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$. Here $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is the transition map from $\phi$ to $\psi$ (which is a map between open subsets of $\mathbb R^m$) and $d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$ is its standard derivative in the sense of multivariable calculus.

These requirements tell us how to construct $T_pM$. We denote by $\mathfrak C(M,p)$ the set of all charts $\phi : U \to U'$ on $M$ such that $p \in U$.

Let us begin by cumulating the vector spaces $T_{\phi(p)}U'  =\mathbb R^m$ for all $\phi \in \mathfrak C(M,p)$. Formally this produces the set
$$\mathbb T_pM = \mathbb R^m \times \mathfrak C(M,p) .$$
The vector spaces $\mathbb R^m \times \{\phi\} \equiv \mathbb R^m = T_pU'_\phi$ and $\mathbb R^m \times \{\psi\} \equiv \mathbb R^m = T_pU'_\psi$ for $\phi,\psi \in  \mathfrak C(M,p)$ will be identified non-trivially via the isomorphism  $d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$. That is, on $\mathbb T_pM$ we define an equivalence relation by $(v,\phi) \sim (w,\psi)$ if $w = d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(v)$. Now let
$$T_pM  = \mathbb T_pM/\sim. $$
The equivalence classes with respect to $\sim$ are subsets of $\mathbb T_pM$ containing precisely one element of each $\mathbb R^m \times \{\phi\}$. Thus each inclusion $i_\phi : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb T_pM, i_\phi(v) = (v,\phi)$, induces a bijection $\iota_\phi : \mathbb R^m = T_pU' \to T_pM, \iota_\phi(v) = [v,\phi]$. By construction
$$\iota_\psi \circ d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} = \iota_\phi \tag{$*$}$$
for all $\phi,\psi \in  \mathfrak C(M,p)$.

Each bijection $\iota_\phi$ induces a unique vector space structure on $T_pM$ making $\iota_\phi$ an isomorphism and because or $(*)$ all these vector space structures on $T_pM$ agree.

Let us now check the above requirements.

1. Each open $M \subset \mathbb R^m$ has $id_M$ as a canonical chart, thus $\iota_{id_M} : \mathbb R^m \to T_pM$ is a canonical isomorphism which allows to identify $T_pM \equiv \mathbb R^m$.
2. Let $U \subset M$ be an open neighborhood of $p \in M$. Then $\mathfrak C(U,p) \subset \mathfrak C(M,p)$ and thus by definition we get a canonical isomorphism $j_U  : T_pU = (\mathbb T_pU/\sim) \to  (\mathbb T_pM/\sim) = T_pM$.
3. Given $\phi \in \mathfrak C(M,p)$, we take $d\phi_p = \iota_\phi^{-1} : T_pM \to \mathbb R^m$.
4. This is now obvious; it is a reformulation of $(*)$.

Let us remark that our definition of $T_pM$ is a special case of a *direct limit construction*.

What is the relation to the "derivatives of curves" approach in your question?

To each curve $u : J \to M$ through $p$ we can associate the equivalence class $$\theta(u) = [(\phi\circ u)'(0),\phi] \in T_p M $$
where $\phi \in \mathfrak C(M,p)$ is arbitrary. Its representative in the $\mathbb R^m \times \{\psi\}$-subset of $\mathbb T_pM$ is $((\psi\circ u)'(0),\psi)$. Thus the vector $u'(0) = \theta(u)$ subsumes all "localized derivatives" of $u$.

Clearly $\theta(u) = \theta(v)$ iff $u$ and $v$ are equivalent in the sense of your question. Thus we get a bijection between the set of equivalence classes of curves through $p$ and our $T_pM$. In other words, our $T_p M$ is indeed a variant of the tangent space defined by equivalence classes of curves through $p$, but the vector $u'(0) = \theta(u)$ is certainly closer to intuition than $[u]$.

The above definition of $T_pM$ also nicely shows how to endow the tangent bundle
$$T M = \bigcup_{p \in M} \{p\} \times T_p M$$
with a topology and a smooth structure. In fact, for each $\phi \in \mathfrak C(M,p)$ we get a canonical fiber-preserving  bijection
$$\tau_\phi : \bigcup_{p \in U} \{p\} \times T_p M \to U \times \mathbb  R^m, \tau_\phi(p,v) = (p,d\phi_p(v)) .$$

If $f : M \to N$ is smooth, we have the localized derivatives $d_{(\phi,\psi)} f_p  = d(\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$. Define
$$df_p =  d\psi_{f(p)}^{-1} \circ d_{(\phi,\psi)}f_p \circ d\phi_p : T_pM  \to T_{f(p)}N .$$

It is easy to verify that $df_p$ does not depend on the charts $\phi, \psi$. By definition the diagrams

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_pM @>{df_p}>> T_{f(p)}N \\
@V{d\phi_p}VV @V{d\psi_{f(p)}}VV \\
\mathbb R^m @>{d_{(\phi,\psi)} f_p}>> \mathbb R^m \end{CD}
commute which nicely shows that the localized derivatives of $f$ at $p$ are not that bad as they appear at first glance. In fact, $df_p$ subsumes all these maps.

For a curve $u : J \to M$ through $p$ we get the derivative
$$du_0 : \mathbb R = T_0J \to T_pM .$$
By construction we have $du_0(1) = u'(0)$.

What about the isomorphism $d\phi_p : T_pM \to \mathbb R^m = T_{\phi(p)} U'$ which was defined above in a very formal way to identify $T_pM$ with $\mathbb R^m$? We have a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_pM =T_pU @>{d\phi_p}>> T_{\phi(p)}U' \\
@V{d\phi_p}VV @V{d(id_{U'})_{\phi(p)}}VV \\
\mathbb R^m @>{d_{(\phi,id_{U'})} \phi_p}>> \mathbb R^m \end{CD}
where the horizontal $d\phi_p$ is the derivative of $\phi$ at $p$ and the vertical $d\phi_p$  is our formal isomorphism. But
$$d_{(\phi,id_{U'})} \phi_p= d(id_{U'} \circ \phi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} = id$$

which shows that both interpretations of $d\phi_p$ are identical.

Finally, let us consider smooth maps $f : (M,p) \to (N,q)$ from $M$ to $N$ mapping a fixed $p \in M$ to a fixed $q \in N$.  The function $\theta$ assigning to $f$ its derivative $df_p : T_pM \to T_qN$ is easily seen to be a surjection from the set of all smooth maps $(M,p) \to (N,q)$ to the vector space of all linear maps $T_pM \to T_qN$. Clearly $\theta(f) = \theta(g)$ defines an equivalence relation $f \sim g$ for smooth maps $(M,p) \to (N,q)$. As for tangent vectors one can therefore identify $df_p$ with the equivalence class $[f]$ of $f$ which results in an alternative definition of the derivative.

This is precisely what is done for the cotangent space $T^*_pM$: The derivative $df_p : T_pM \to T_{f(p)}\mathbb R = \mathbb R$ is interpreted as the equivalence class $[f]$.

*Remark 1:*

Moishe Kohan comments that the above construction of $T_pM$ is closely related to an alternative description of the tangent bundle $TM$. This can be obtained by gluing all trivial bundles $B_\phi = U \times \mathbb R^m$ over the domains of charts $\phi : U \to U'$ via the transition maps of the fibers. Technically this is done via the maps $\tau_{(\phi,\psi)}: U \cap V \to GL(\mathbb R^m),\tau(p) = d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$. The fiber $T_pM$ of the "glued bundle" $TM$ is thus obtained by gluing the collection of all $\{p\} \times \mathbb R^m_\phi = \{p\} \times \mathbb R^m$ with $p$ in the domain of $\phi$ via the transition maps $d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$ (note that $p$ is always in the common part $U \cap V$ of all charts $\phi, \psi$ around $p$). This is in fact nothing else than the above construction.

*Remark 2:*

One more alternative construction of $T_pM$ goes as follows. Consider the vector space $\mathbf T_pM = (\mathbb R^m)^{\mathfrak C(M,p)} = \prod_{\phi \in \mathfrak C(M,p)} \mathbb R^m$ and define
$$T_pM  =\{(v_ϕ)∈\mathbf T_pM \mid d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(v_ϕ)=v_ψ \text{ for all } ϕ,ψ \in \mathfrak C(M,p)\}.$$
It is easy to check that is a linear subspace of $\mathbf T_pM$. The product projections $\pi_\phi: \mathbf T_pM \to \mathbb R^m$ restrict to linear maps $d\phi_p : T_pM \to \mathbb R^m$ which are easily seen to be isomorphisms. Verification of 1. - 4. is straightforward.

Let us remark that this definition of $T_pM$ is a special case of an *inverse limit construction*.

Comment: Needless to say, this definition requires much more sophistication on the part of the reader than either  one of the standard definitions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes. The alternative definition is by no means elementary and involves non-standard ingredients like the direct or inverse limit (although I avoided to use these formal concepts in a recent update).  Certainly inadequate for beginners.

Comment: I did not read in detail, but it seems that you are building the tangent bundle using the natural transition maps. (Which is a special case of the general construction of forming a vector bundle from transition maps.) If so, it might be worth pointing this out. In a way, this was the early approach to tensors on manifolds before things got formalized and this is how physicists (and many analysts) still think. (A tensor field on a manifold is a collection of objects in local charts which transform according to some rule under transition maps.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan  You are right, thank you for pointing this out. I included a remark.